# how can i access firebase nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Hey , I want to access appliers node's data , anyone can tell me what is the best practice for fetching data from root level to targeted node as i discussed appliers node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I52GW.jpg)

[Here is Code present that i am tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3jOz.jpg)

```
import React from "react"
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import NavBarSignOut from '../navBar/navBarSignOut';
import {Link,browserHistory} from 'react-router';




class Candidiate extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          myProfile : [],
          jobKeys : []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const refRoot = firebase.database().ref();
        const rootRef = refRoot.child('jobs');
        rootRef.on('value',snapshot=>{
            var userObj = snapshot.val();
               console.log(userObj);            
             let vm = this;
             let obj = [];
             let keys = [];
                Object.keys(userObj).forEach(function (key) {
                 obj = userObj[key]       
                 keys.push(key);
            vm.state.myProfile.push(obj)
            vm.setState({ myProfile: vm.state.myProfile,  
                            jobKeys : keys
                          })
                });    
     })
              const apply =  rootRef.child(this.state.jobKeys+'/appliers').on('value',snap=>{
                    var apply = snap.val();
                    console.log(apply);
                    let a = [];
                    Object.keys(apply).forEach(function (key){
                        a = apply[key];
                        console.log(a);
                        this.setState({myProfile : this.state.a})
                    })
                })      
    }

    render(){
        return  firebase.auth().currentUser ? (
            <div>
                <NavBarSignOut />
               <center> <h1>Profile</h1> </center>
                 {this.state.myProfile.map((data , index) => (
                         <div key={index} className="container">

    <table className="table">
        <thead >
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Education</th>
        <th>Skills</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>GPA</th>   
        <th>Experience</th>                
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{data.sName}</td>
        <td>{data.education}</td>
        <td>{data.skills}</td>
        <td>{data.sEmail}</td>
        <td>{data.gpa}</td>
        <td>{data.experience}</td>        
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>      ))}
 <Link to="student" className="btn btn-primary">
    Go Back student Panel
  </Link>
            </div>
        ) : ( <div>{browserHistory.push('login')}</div> )
    }
}
export default Candidiate;
```

**JSON DATA:**

```
{
  "jobs" : {
    "-KpdYaI_E5Vp39bkeFww" : {
      "appliers" : {
        "JfUXMVNDrnVcnOkn8tZ1LfUFf2P2" : {
          "education" : "cma",
          "experience" : "not",
          "gpa" : "4",
          "sEmail" : "talha@gmail.com",
          "sId" : "JfUXMVNDrnVcnOkn8tZ1LfUFf2P2",
          "sName" : "talha",
          "skills" : "finance"
        }
      },
      "companyName" : "panacloud",
      "education" : "",
      "email" : "pana@gmail.com",
      "jobTitle" : "",
      "skills" : "",
      "uid" : "CcyYpW5c3GOcU3ltBIpSSg9cnd33"
    },
    "-KpeKF86tqYdosIOJP8M" : {
      "appliers" : {
        "JfUXMVNDrnVcnOkn8tZ1LfUFf2P2" : {
          "education" : "cma",
          "experience" : "not",
          "gpa" : "4",
          "sEmail" : "talha@gmail.com",
          "sId" : "JfUXMVNDrnVcnOkn8tZ1LfUFf2P2",
          "sName" : "talha",
          "skills" : "finance"
        }
      },
      "companyName" : "ibm",
      "education" : "bcom",
      "email" : "ibm@gmail.com",
      "jobTitle" : "data entry ",
      "skills" : "english",
      "uid" : "TgrXg6Fx0WZFhmNHRY0nxsLxkbL2"
    },
    "-Kpeew-PmNnqEB6f4Q_g" : {
      "companyName" : "ibm",
      "education" : "bscs",
      "email" : "ibm@gmail.com",
      "jobTitle" : "front end",
      "skills" : "html , css ,js",
      "uid" : "TgrXg6Fx0WZFhmNHRY0nxsLxkbL2"
    }
  },
  "update Profile" : {
    "JfUXMVNDrnVcnOkn8tZ1LfUFf2P2" : {
      "education" : "cma",
      "experience" : "not",
      "gpa" : "4",
      "sEmail" : "talha@gmail.com",
      "sId" : "JfUXMVNDrnVcnOkn8tZ1LfUFf2P2",
      "sName" : "talha",
      "skills" : "finance"
    },
    "vGHLdbDPF1YcvFOwzULmc0uIQUF3" : {
      "education" : "fcma",
      "experience" : "no",
      "gpa" : "4",
      "sEmail" : "student@gmail.com",
      "sId" : "vGHLdbDPF1YcvFOwzULmc0uIQUF3",
      "sName" : "student",
      "skills" : "taxation"
    }
  },
  "user" : {
    "CcyYpW5c3GOcU3ltBIpSSg9cnd33" : {
      "typeOfUser" : "company",
      "uEmail" : "pana@gmail.com",
      "uName" : "panacloud",
      "uPassword" : "12345678"
    },
    "JfUXMVNDrnVcnOkn8tZ1LfUFf2P2" : {
      "typeOfUser" : "student",
      "uEmail" : "talha@gmail.com",
      "uName" : "talha",
      "uPassword" : "12345678"
    },
    "TgrXg6Fx0WZFhmNHRY0nxsLxkbL2" : {
      "typeOfUser" : "company",
      "uEmail" : "ibm@gmail.com",
      "uName" : "ibm",
      "uPassword" : "12345678"
    },
    "vGHLdbDPF1YcvFOwzULmc0uIQUF3" : {
      "typeOfUser" : "student",
      "uEmail" : "student@gmail.com",
      "uName" : "student",
      "uPassword" : "12345678"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please present us some code you've tried with

Comment: i am editing my post and present the code that i am tried

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text of the code and the data structure as JSON. You can get the code from your IDE, and the JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Having them as text makes your question more easily readable and answerable. Links are not nearly as useful (as they tend to rot).

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen i edit my post as per your instruction , please check it again .

Comment: Thanks for that. Now what is the problem with this code? Note that you shared quite some code, so help us focus on where you have a problem. What line isn't doing what you expected it to do?

Comment: Basically I want to access data of appliers node i am fetched data of the jobs node but how can i fetch data that is availble under the appliers folder , what is the logic of firebase behind this